# sending dynamic data to custom activity with pushe

Tags: android, pushe

I am using Pushe for push notification service. When sending a notification, I can name an activity to get opened when user clicks on it.

I am sending some json content with my notification which contains a link. My problem is that I want to use this link to open an activity (Ex: opening a this link in my custom WebView Activity) I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pushe` does open the activity you want by just naming it in click action of your notification. You also can send a `json` with your notification. If you need this `json data` in the activity that `Pushe library` will open, you can save it in `SharedPreferences` and add some code to your activity to get this data from `SharedPreferences`. So if for example you want to send a link in json to be used in your `WebViewActivity`, you need to add below codes:

In json receiver class:

```
public class MyPushListener extends PusheListenerService {
   @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(JSONObject message,JSONObject content){
       android.util.Log.i("Pushe","Custom json Message: "+     message.toString());
        // Your Code
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("_appname_prefes", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
       editor.putString("url", message.getString("link", null));
       editor.commit();
    }
}
```

"link" is the key of your link in the json that you send and "url" is the key for saving it in the `SharedPreferences`.

In your `WebViewActivity`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("_appname_prefes", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String url = prefs.getString("url", null);
if (url != null) {
   //set this link to ur webview
}else{
   //show some default page instead
}
```